# Adicionar Estilo Css em uma ViewPort de uma página específica no visual studio bootstrap

Tags: css, viewport

sou novo com CSS e estou estudando alguns elementos.

Ao Criar um projeto ASP.NET CORE MVC com o Visual Studio 2017, automaticamente todo o conteúdo já é colocado dentro de um body-content que mantém o conteúdo centralizado. (Pelo menos foi o que entendi)

Em uma página específica, estou utilizando um ViewPort, onde eu gostaria que todo o comprimento da página fosse preenchido por ele, sem alterar o body-content nas outras páginas...

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

.nome-pagina .body-content{
     width: 100%;
}

e sem entender direito tentei fazer o inverso:
.body-content .nome-pagina{
     width: 100%;
}

porém o resultado que consegui foi alterar o CSS para todas as páginas, mas repito, gostaria de alterar apenas para uma página específica.

Obrigado.

HTML DA PÁGINA:

```
    <section class="conteudo-cadastro">
        <div class="content">

        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.conteudo-cadastro {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #747640;
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde @L Thomaz, o que ocorre é que provavelmente o body-content esta herdando um tamanho que não seja 100% da viewport, logo quando você coloca `width 100%` no body-content ele vai ocupar o tamanho do pai dele. verifique quem é o pai do body-content e veja qual o tamanho do width dele. Post o css e um pouco do html para olharmos, se possível.

Comment: Olá @AndersonMendes, primeiramente agradeço o interesse em responder, como posso identificar quem é o elemento pai do body content?

Comment: Provavelmente vai ser a tag body ou html, o html é apenas isso? A classe .body-content esta no body?

Comment: O HTML é apenas isso pois ainda não adicionei nenhum conteúdo, estou tentando entender os elementos. Quanto ao body-content estar dentro do body, se isso acontece é implicitamente de alguma forma feita pelo próprio visual studio, pois na página em si, ela  é iniciada com a section, exatamente do jeito que está.

Comment: A sua visão da pagina é semelhante a esta aqui [CODEPEN PAGE](https://codepen.io/andersonmendesdev/pen/EOveJO) e você quer remover esses espaços em branco do lado?

Comment: @AndersonMendes Exatamente, quero remover os espaços em branco das laterais, é exatamente isso. Quero que lateralmente, minha viewport preencha 100% do espaço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver seu problema é bem simples é remover as margens do `body` adicionando margin: 0 ao body e remover o padding do `.body-content`, na resposta eu só comentei o padding left e right mas você deve remove los, sua section `conteudo-cadastro` vai ocupar 100% da viewport, mas vai afetar as outras paginas, o tamanho das section você que vai ter que definir.

> Padding é distancia interna em relação a sua borda ou distância interna do conteudo em relação a borda. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/padding)
>
> Margin é a distância externa das suas bordas em relação a outros componentes. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

```css
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0; 
}

.body-content {
    //padding-left: 15px;
    //padding-right: 15px;
}

.conteudo-cadastro {
    margin-top: 4px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #747640;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-content">
        <section class="conteudo-cadastro">
                <div class="content">
      
                </div>
         </section>
   </div>
```